# How to copy all textbox values of a div to another div textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to copy the contents of a textbox of a particular `div` into another `div`.

I am looping through a products array which contains all the products and then I am checking with parentChildMapping to see if that product has children or not.

If we are entering values for min, max, typ and then adding a child then I want all those values which we entered for min, max, typ to be copied.

[image]

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <script src="jquery-2.2.5.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="parent_child_mapping.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="products.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="app.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="indexController.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <style>
            .clsProductDetailsHldr .well
            {
                padding-top: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 4px;
            }
            .inputError
            {
                border: 1px solid red;
                background-color: antiquewhite;
            }
            .row
            {
                margin-bottom: 4px;
            }
        </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="productspoc">
    <div ng-controller="indexCtrl">
      <div class="container clsProductDetailsHldr">
        <div ng-repeat="product in products track by $index">

          <div class="well" ng-class="{'col-sm-6':!checkIfProductHasChildren(product)}">
            <div class="row">
              <span class="" ng-class="{'col-sm-10':checkIfProductHasChildren(product),'col-sm-4':!checkIfProductHasChildren(product)}">{{product}}</span>
              <span class="col-sm-4" ng-if="!checkIfProductHasChildren(product)">
                <input type="text" value="" ng-model="productsObj[''+product]" />
              </span>
              <span class="col-sm-2" ng-if="checkIfProductHasChildren(product)">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Add Child" ng-click="addChildToParent(product)" />
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-11">
                <span class="col-sm-10" ng-if="checkIfNewChild(product,key)">
                  <input type="button" class="btn" value="Remove Child" ng-click="removeChildFromParent(product, key)" />
                </span>
                <div class="col-sm-4" ng-if="checkIfProductHasChildren(product)" ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in productsObj[''+product] track by $index">
                  <span class="col-sm-2">{{key1}}</span>
                  <span class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" ng-focus="onInputFocus($event)" value="" ng-model="productsObj[''+product][''+key1]" />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
          <span>
            <input type="button" value="clear" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="onClearClick()" />
          </span>
          <span>
            <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="onSaveClick()" />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(".clsAddChild").click(function()
            {
                var newChild = "";
                newChild+= '<div class="row">';
                    newChild+= '<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left:20px;"><span>NewChild Child 1</span></div>';
                newChild+= '</div>';
                newChild+= '<div class="row">';
                    newChild+= '<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left:25px;"><span>NewChild Child 1 child 1</span><span><input type="text" /></span></div>';
                    newChild+= '<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left:25px;"><span>NewChild Child 1 child 2</span><span><input type="text" /></span></div>';
                    newChild+= '<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left:25px;"><span>NewChild Child 1 child 3</span><span><input type="text" /></span></div>';
                    newChild+= '<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left:25px;"><span>NewChild Child 1 child 4</span><span><input type="text" /></span></div>';
                    newChild+= '<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left:25px;"><span>NewChild Child 1 child 5</span><span><input type="text" /></span></div>';
                newChild+= '</div>';

                $(this).closest(".parentChildWrapper").append(newChild);
            });

        </script>
  </body>

</html>

indexController.js
angular.module('productspoc')
  .controller('indexCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.productsObj = {};
    $scope.products = products;
    $scope.parentChildMapping = parentChildMapping;

    $scope.checkIfProductHasChildren = function(product)
    {
        return product in $scope.parentChildMapping;
    };
    $scope.addChildToParent = function(parent)
    {
         var porductIndex = products.indexOf(parent);
         products.splice(porductIndex + 1, 0, parent + 1);
         $scope.parentChildMapping[parent +1]= parent + 1;
         $scope.productsObj[""+parent +1]= {"Min": "","Typ":"","Max": ""};
         console.log($scope.productsObj);
    };

    $scope.checkIfNewChild = function(product,key)
    {
        if(( product.indexOf("1") ===2 || product.indexOf("1") ===3 ||product.indexOf("1") ===4))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };

    $scope.removeChildFromParent = function(product, key)
    {
        delete $scope.productsObj[""+product];
        var porductIndex = products.indexOf(product); 
        products.splice( porductIndex, 1 );

    };

    $scope.onClearClick = function()
    {
        var r=confirm("Are you sure, wanted to reload the page. If yes then click on OK, else Cancel and resume your work.");
        if (r==true){
            window.location.reload();
            angular.element(".clsProductDetailsHldr input[type='text']").val("");
        }
        else{ 
        }
    };

    $scope.validateNumberFields = function()
    {
        var isValid = true;
        angular.forEach(angular.element(".clsProductDetailsHldr .onlyNumbers"), function(value, index){
            if(isNaN(angular.element(value).val()))
            {
                isValid = false;
                angular.element(value).addClass("inputError");
            }
        });

        return isValid;
    };

    $scope.onInputFocus = function(event)
    {
        angular.element(event.currentTarget).removeClass("inputError");
    };

    $scope.onSaveClick = function()
    {
        var isValid = $scope.validateNumberFields();
        if(!isValid)
        {
            alert("Selected Input feild has invalid number");
            return;
        }

        angular.forEach($scope.productsObj, function(value, key){
            if(value instanceof Object && value.hasOwnProperty('newChildCount'))
                delete value.newChildCount;

            if(value instanceof Object)
            {
                angular.forEach(value, function(value1, key1)
                {
                    // Below code will check 
                    // key1 should not be a Note and value1 should have some value 
                    if(key1!=='Note' && value1)
                    {
                        console.log(value1.length)
                        var pram = value1.substring(value1.length-1, value1.length);
                        switch (pram)
                        {
                            case "n":
                            value1 = (value1.substring(0,value1.length-1))*.000000001;
                            break;
                            case "p":
                            value1 = (value1.substring(0,value1.length-1))*.000000000001;
                            break;
                            case "m":
                            value1 = (value1.substring(0,value1.length-1))*.001;
                            break;
                            case "u":
                            value1 = (value1.substring(0,value1.length-1))*.000001;
                            break;
                            case "k":
                            value1 = (value1.substring(0,value1.length-1))*1000;
                            break;
                            case "M":
                            value1 = (value1.substring(0,value1.length-1))*1000000;
                            break;
                            case "G":
                            value1 = (value1.substring(0,value1.length-1))*1000000000;
                            break;
                            default:
                            value1;
                            break;
                        }
                        $scope.productsObj[key][key1] = value1 ;
                        console.log(pram);
                    }
                    console.log(value1);

                });
            }
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.productsObj));
        console.log($scope.productsObj);
        var sub=confirm("Data will be saved on click of OK button.");
        if (sub==true)
        {
            $.ajax({
                      url: "/rest/products/add/",
                      type: "POST",
                      dataType: "json", // expected format for response
                      contentType: "application/json", // send as JSON
                      data: JSON.stringify($scope.productsObj),
                      complete: function() {
                          $window.location.href = "#/success.html";
                            alert( "Data saved to database: " + data );
                            console.log('success response' + response)
                      },

                      success: function(data) {
                          $window.location.href = "#/success.html";
                        alert( "Data saved to database: " + data );
                        console.log('success response' + response)
                     },

                      error: function() {
                        //called when there is an error
                      },
                    });
        }
        else
        {

        }
    };

    $scope.initProductDetails = function()
    {
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.products.length;i++)
        {
            if($scope.products[i] in parentChildMapping)
            {
                $scope.productsObj[""+$scope.products[i]] = {};
                $scope.productsObj[""+$scope.products[i]].newChildCount = 0;
                $scope.productsObj[""+$scope.products[i]] = {"Min": "","Typ":"","Max": ""};
            }
            else
                $scope.productsObj[""+products[i]] = "";
        }
    };
    $scope.initProductDetails();

}]);

     products.js
     products = [
"Part_Number",
"Name",
"Code",
"absmax_1",
"absmax_2",
"absmax_3",
"absmax_4"
]


   parent_Child_Mapping.js
    parentChildMapping ={
"absmax_1":"absmax_1",
"absmax_2":"absmax_2",
"absmax_3":"absmax_3",
"absmax_4":"absmax_4",
}
```

Comment: What you have tried yet ?

Comment: What is the code you are using?  I saw AngularJS tag, but nothing to match it.  Can you please provide more details?

Please mind that the downvotes to your question are not because the question sounds trivial to many, but it does not give complete information to help you.  Please follow the below link for help with asking good questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hard start for a new comer,
better delete the question before someone posts an answer, or you won't be able to delete it

Comment: Now I have copied the complete code here, can someone please check, as I am new to this UI stuff and trying to fathom the solution for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all elements he wants to clone in a div and clone that whole div. Below is an small sample code showing such behavior:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function cloneMe(){
                var tT = document.querySelectorAll('.Content > div'); //All the div inside .Content;
                var tL = tT[tT.length - 1]; //The last div - the one to get copied

                var tC = tL.cloneNode(true);// Deep cloning the last div 'tL'
                tL.parentNode.appendChild(tC) //Adding the copy to the parent of the last div 'tL'
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick = 'cloneMe()'>Add</button>
        <div class = 'Content'>
            <div>
                <input  name = 'min' type = 'text' placeholder = 'min' />
                <input  name = 'typ' type = 'text' placeholder = 'typ' />
                <input  name = 'max' type = 'text' placeholder = 'max' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is adding element in same div, not in new div

Comment: @experimenter: Well, it does copy the parent div of the input, not the div.Content. A man would have to attribute it to fit his needs.